# Array jQuery - Remover indices e concatenar html

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou realizando uma chamada ajax que me retona o Html de filtros a serem postos em uma determinada div.
Contudo gostaria de remover alguns elementos do html previamente. Para isso passei o html para o jQuery, assim transformando-o em um array.
Apos remover os elementos gostaria de retomar o html concatenado.

Atualmente estou fazendo assim:

```
msg = jQuery(msg);
var index = 0;
var html = '';
msg.each(function(i, _this){
    if(jQuery(_this).find('input[type="submit"]').size() == 1){
        index = i;
        return;
    }
});
msg.splice(index,2);
msg.each(function(){
    html += this.outerHTML
});
```

[Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lwfuxa3t/2/)

Mas não estou muito contente com o desenvolvimento, alguém saberia como deixar essa função melhor?

Comment: Se você quer remover todos os elementos do tipo submit, pq não fazer um select usando a msg como contexto e remover todos os elementos retornados pelo select

Comment: A resposta do TobyMosque é uma forma satisfatória de fazer, mas você deve estar se perguntando: e se `msg` ainda não estiver no DOM? Bom, como JavaScript é **síncrono**, você pode acrescentar `msg` ao DOM, fazer as operações que quiser, e até mesmo retirar do DOM depois, que tudo isso vai acontecer sem nenhum artefato visual na tela (i.e. a IU só será atualizada depois que seu código JavaScript retornar). Só lembre-se de adaptar o seletor para levar em conta o elemento (talvez temporário) onde você acrescentou `msg`, se necessário.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vou te dá dois conselhos:

1. jQuery não é uma ferramenta obrigatoria para manipular o DOM.
2. Você não precisa recriar todos os elementos para poder remover um nó.

```js
var submits = document.querySelectorAll("p input[type='submit']")
[].forEach.call(submits, function (elemento, indice) {
  elemento.parentNode.removeChild(elemento);
});
```

```html
<p class="left">
 <input name="teste1" type="text" />
</p>
<p class="left">
 <input name="teste2" type="text" />
</p>
<p class="left">
 <input name="teste3" type="text" />
</p>
<p class="left">
 <input name="teste4" type="text" />
</p>
<p class="left">
 <input name="teste5" type="text" />
</p>
<p class="left">
 <input type="submit" />
</p>
```

Comment: Esse `slice` é só pra transformar um nodeList em um array? Se for, também dá pra simplesmente fazer `[].forEach.call(submits, function(...) { ... })`.

Comment: Sim, muito bem apontado.

Comment: Muito bom, gostei, por isso que tenho q aprender mais javascript = D

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando da resposta fornecida pelo @TobyMosque e pesquisando mais um pouco.

Cheguei a esta solução, que se adequá mais ao caso, pois como comentei o HTML vem via Ajax. Ou Seja é uma string, então basicamente eu gostaria de tratar a string.

```
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(msg, 'text/html');
var submits = doc.querySelectorAll("P input[type='submit']");
[].forEach.call(submits, function (elemento, indice){
    elemento.parentNode.removeChild(elemento);
});
var htmlFinal = doc.body.innerHTML
```

Comment: dá uma olhada neste [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/domparser-vs-innerhtml-vs-createhtmldocument/4), talvez seja interessante criar uma `div` para fazer um wrap do `html` do que usar o `DOMParser` para criar um documento.